# Zerigo DNS on Heroku error after app removed and recreated

Tags: heroku, dns, zerigo

im having a problem with Heroku and Zerigo DNS.
Im using Zerigo to make DNS work on heroku, the problem began when i delete the app to rebuild all my web site.
Once i delete and rebuild i couldn't install Zerigo DNS to the new app. The problem is even worse because my domain still works!

As you guys can see, when you access http://www.estatisticaslotofacil.com.br, you are redirect to a web site. This site is hosted on heroku using Zerigo DNS.
But i dont install Zerigo to this new app, because it keeps giving me this message:

**! could not create zone; already registered on Zerigo to a different account?**

Can someone help solve this?

Comment: We are tracking this in Zerigo support tickets. Looks to be an issue between Heroku and Zerigo. We will work with Heroku engineering to get a resolution as quickly as possible.

Comment: Thanks... it doens't impact my app in anyway, but perhaps others could face this problem.